# Mongodb aggregation with days between two dates

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregation

I have two dates, I need to get all days (Mar 1, 2018 | Mar 2, 2018 ...) between those dates. And I need to get sum of amount on documents. 
For example,

```
[
{id:1, date: 1519833600, type: "sms", amount: 130.00},
{id:4, date: 1519833600, type: "sms", amount: 130.00},
{id:2, date: 1519920000, type: "chat", amount: 480.00},
{id:3, date: 1519920000, type: "sms", amount: 130.00},
]
```

The result with dates Mar 1 to Mar 6 will be,

[

```
{date: "Mar 1, 2018", sms: 260.00, chat: 0},
{date: "Mar 2, 2018", sms: 130.00, chat: 480},
{date: "Mar 3, 2018", sms: 0, chat: 0},
{date: "Mar 4, 2018", sms: 0, chat: 0},
{date: "Mar 5, 2018", sms: 0, chat: 0},
{date: "Mar 6, 2018", sms: 0, chat: 0},
]
```

I tried using $project but I am not successful. Can you give me a sample pipeline for this? I am really not good in aggregation.

As requested, here is my attempt:

```
[
{
    $match: {gte: <date>, lt: <date>},
},
{
    $group: {
        _id: null,
        sms: { $sum: "$amount"}
    }
}
]
```

I don't know how to divide the sum amount into different types (for example, sms: 400 , chat:300). Then I don't know how to get it by date (mar 1, mar 2 ...).

Comment: Your pipeline should be `[
 { "$match": { "date": { "$gte": new Date("2018-03-01"), "$lte": new Date("2018-03-06")} }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": { "$dateToString": { "format": "%Y-%m-%d", "date": "$date" } },
         "sms": {
   "$sum": {
    "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$type", "sms" ] }, 1, 0 ]
   }
  },
         "chat": {
   "$sum": {
    "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$type", "chat" ] }, 1, 0 ]
   }
  }
    }}
]`

Comment: it says, invalid operator '$dateToString'